# How can I set a UILabel to change after a certain amount of time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, time, uilabel

I am trying to make a UILabel change every 24 hours and I have tried using the method from this article: [Changing a UILabel after a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281691/changing-a-uilabel-after-a-specific-time) but I do not know how to save the time so the app knows that the timer has been running for 24 hours. Should I be using a different approach? Maybe using the date and when the date changes to change the UILabel? The only problem is that I do not want people to be able to just advance their clocks or change their dates of their devices to see what the UILabel changes to. My goal is trying to make a quote of the day app. Please Help.

Comment: Since you can't store an infinite number of quotes on the device for an infinite number of days anyway, it seems as if you best bet is to store the data on a server. That way, you can use changes in the system time as an indication to check for an update and give the user the quote that aligns with server's "current" date, so that if the user advances their clock it won't be so critical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is querying an ntp (Network Time Protocol) service.

1. Query NTP
2. Save the result (User defaults is probably simplest)
3. Set timer (you could check every hour)
4. On timer fire re query NTP and validate it has truly passed 24 hours
5. Change the label

Comment: Okay so say I just wanted to keep a text document with all the quotes and just have a timer that changes the UILabel after a certain amount of time. Or better yet lets not talk about my case specifically. How would I be able to keep track of time even after the application closes? I don't think an NSTimer is the best option but I do not know of any other option to record time. Is there a way to look at the internal clock inside of the phone?

Comment: Timer is there only to trigger the action.  You save the initial time and measure the offset from NTP. This will give you the right time regardless of the app running or not. scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats: